# i try to search in laravel with ajax . i post two variables but my query doesnt work well this is my code

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i try to search in laravel with ajax . i post two variables but my query doesn't work well this is my code

```
    public function search(Request $request){
    $tag= $request->tag;
    $selected = $request->selected;

        $selected = "'" . implode ( "','", $selected ) . "'";

    $output = '';
    if ($tag != '')
    {
        $data= DB::table('tags')->where('name','like','%'.$tag.'%')->whereNotIn('name',[$selected])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    }
    $total_row = $data->count();
    if($total_row > 0)
    {
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<a>'.$row->tag_name.'</a>';
        }
    }

    return Response()->json($output);
}
```

**my problem is $selected i converted it to string = 'one','two','three' but doesn't work **

Answer (score 0):

Your `$output` is not an array but you convert it to json response?
and `Response()->json()` is not a helper you should use `response()->json()`. I don't have any idea about your query but change top tips and check results.